# .zshrcを編集していたら、コマンドラインが長くて邪魔な状態になってしまいました。

Tags: zsh

.zshrcを編集していたら、コマンドラインが長くて邪魔な状態になってしまいました。
元に戻すにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Answer (score 1):

コマンドライン？　プロンプトでは？　とりあえず `PS1=$`  と手入力すれば、そのシェルに限りプロンプトが短くなります。今後起動するシェルでも短くしたいなら `~/.zshrc` 中にて環境変数 `PS1` を設定している行を見つけて再編集してください。

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/zshrc` の中では `PROMPT` 変数のデフォルトが以下のように設定されているので、
これをお手本に `~/.zshrc` を編集し直してみてください。

```sh
# Set prompts
PROMPT='[%n@%m]%~%# '    # default prompt
```